# subquery returning more than 1 row trying to get price today and yesterday from a sku

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to query a database to get the price of a sku today and yesterday.
This is my query:

```
select ii2.SKU_config,

(select distinct bsh.unit_price
from tricae_business.bob_stock_history bsh
left join `data_warehouse`.item_info ii0 on ii0.id_item_info = bsh.id_catalog_simple
where date(bsh.date) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 0 day) and ii0.sku_config = sku_config
group by ii0.sku_config) preco_hoje,
(select distinct bsh.unit_price
from tricae_business.bob_stock_history bsh
left join `data_warehouse`.item_info ii1 on ii1.id_item_info = bsh.id_catalog_simple
where date(bsh.date) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 1 day) and ii1.sku_config = sku_config
group by ii1.sku_config) preco_ontem


from `data_warehouse`.item_info ii2
group by sku_config
limit 2
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Subquery returns more than 1 row
```

Answer (score 2):

by the looks of it, you are grabbing three columns from `data_warehouse`.item_info ii2. In one of your two subqueries, you are probably grabbing multiple rows, which is not allowed.

Try running the subqueries by themselves and see what they each return

Comment: I ran and it brings the prices of the respectives skus, but the skus are not duplicated